# Android GooglePlayServices context error

Tags: java, android, class, android-context

I'm trying to make a Google play services check for my android application. 
I followed a yt guide at this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2lKeTJpaWc
And created the following code:

```
public boolean servicesOK() {
    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google Play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

The code executed correctly without any problems, so i decided to make it into an class file. Thats when the problems occurred; i get the following error-message:

```
"The method isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context) in the type GooglePlayServicesUtil is not applicable for the arguments (PlayServices)"
```

The complete code for the class:

```
package com.test.testmaps2;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

public class PlayServices {
private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;


public boolean servicesOK() {
    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google Play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests you need to pass `Context` to `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable`. For that you will probably want to fetch the context as an argument to your servicesOK method:

```
public boolean servicesOK(Context ctx) {
    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(ctx);
```

Then call this method from your activity like:

```
servicesOK(this);
```